# In DUB, how do I conditionally compile code based on optional dependencies?

Tags: d, dub

If I have a DUB-based project with an optional dependency, how to I make it so that some code (be it modules or a version(...){...} block) only gets compiled if the dependency is chosen?  Is there a way I can make a version identifier defined based on whether the dependency is present or absent?

I have already read about the "optional" and "default" attributes of the "dependency" tag as documented [here](https://code.dlang.org/package-format?lang=sdl#version-specs).  This allows me to define a dependency as optional, but it lacks teeth if I can't version my code to reflect the dependencies chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can, I am not sure but it seems you can use something like this:

```
version(Have_name_of_dependency)
```

So if your optional dependency would be sdlang-d you could use

```
Have_sdlang_d
```

Same as [here](https://github.com/dlang/dub/blob/68d4f51e7b903e547621b5e53a40434fe7874d8a/source/dub/internal/sdlang/package.d#L32)

This is based on [this](https://github.com/dlang/dub/blob/68d4f51e7b903e547621b5e53a40434fe7874d8a/source/dub/project.d#L605) part of dub code

Comment: I think you nailed it.  Thanks!

I was able to build the project without the dependency by removing it from dub.selections.json and using the version(Have_*) code you suggested.  Unfortunately other projects that depend on that project still insist on including the optional dependency (ex: sdlang-d) in their dependency graph, despite the default=false in the first project and sdlang-d being absent from every dub.selections.json file involved.  But that seems like a different problem... maybe a bug or another question to be asked.

Comment: you should use optional=true

Comment: optional=true was (already) set as well; sorry I assumed it was implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a `version(foo)` block and asking people to use `versions: "foo"` in their dub.sdl, you have one other option. It's cruddy, but it would work.

If your code is a template, you can wrap the relevant stuff in:

```
template HasVibe() 
{
    enum HasVibe = 
        is(typeof(() { import vibe.d; } ));
}

template Foo(T) if (HasVibe!())
{
    // your code here
}
```

If it's *not* a template, you can turn it into a template:

```
template log() if (HasVibe!())
{
    import vibe.core.log : logDebug;
    alias log = logDebug;
}
```

Untested, but it might help in a pinch.